# Is XHTML + SMIL still relevant? Building a rich text editor

Tags: xhtml, rich-text-editor, smil

Are XHTML+SMIL still relevant given recent standards? All material I can find is 4+ years old.

I am researching options to build my own cross-browser-compatible rich text editor and this is one of the options (offered by Microsoft). Mozilla advocates iFrames, but I've always been told frames are a bad practice and would cause problems across browsers anyway.

Comment: Just a note: a `frame` is not the same as an `iframe`. iframes are still going strong, frames are being dropped from the standard. I don't have an answer to your questions however.

Answer (score 0):

I built my own rich editor and use zero frames, frameworks, etc. I'm not sure why you would need/want SMIL for a rich editor. XHTML is completely valid, I serve all my work as application/xhtml+xml and have been updating my web software from XHTML 1.1 to XHTML5 though I consider versionless doctypes invalid as all software should always explicitly declare what version of it's given syntax is. I'm guessing you want to animate editing bits though you could use CSS3 animation and CSS3 transitions just fine and have support for Internet Explorer, a good long term plan is to consider Internet Explorer 10 as your minimal browser to work with. So I say keep XHTML and it's beautiful strictness though go about your goals in a more compatible method.